# Filter channels by categoryId using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to filter channels by `categoryId` with the youtube API

When I do not include `categoryId` in my query params I get the following, which is to be expected.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=(MY_API_KEY_HERE)&categoryId=1&part=id,status,snippet,brandingSettings

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, categoryId, mine, id, forUsername, managedByMe",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, categoryId, mine, id, forUsername, managedByMe",
                "domain": "youtube.parameter",
                "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",
                "location": "parameters.",
                "locationType": "other"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I enter a `categoryId` in the query params using any of the categories I get from this list, though, then I get the following result, which doesn’t make sense since I would assume the `categoryId` is a filter. So why is it `None`?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=(MY_API_KEY_HERE)&categoryId=1&part=id,status,snippet,brandingSettings

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=CA&key=(MY_API_KEY_HERE)

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "youtube.api.CommonRequestError",
                "reason": "ERROR_FILTER_NONE_SELECTED"
            }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Comment: `categoryId` is deprecated according to [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#categoryId). Isn't `topicId` from [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#topicId) what you are looking for ?

Comment: I was trying to use the Channels list instead of the Search list because I was trying to get handle / channel name information from channels where search would give me videos and channels where I didnt want to filter through those and channels list only gave me channels and information on them

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out it was deprecated. I couldn't find anything saying that at the time I posted this question

Comment: Just to make sure that you are aware of it: there is a [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) to YouTube Data API v3 Search: list endpoint, if you set it to `"channel"` you will retrieve only channels and if you set [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#part) to `snippet` you will be able to retrieve channel names in [`item["snippet"]["title"]`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#snippet.title).